# How to change Gerrit LDAP administrator

Tags: gerrit

I have one Gerrit server deployed. My Gerrit server was configured with one LDAP administrator user. Due to some cleanup activity that LDAP user was deleted by LDAP admin. And now I got the new LDAP user. I replaced the user configuration where the last user was configured in secure.config file. And then changed the user at Jenkins as well. And review are going on fine.

After I made the changes in secure.config file with the new user. I was in assumption that this user will become the next administrator of Gerrit. But I can see it is not. And using the old user I am not able to login. Now Hoe can I make the new user as Gerrit admin?

Changed the setting and reverted back, and login again with the new user but no luck.

```
[auth]
    type = development_become_any_account
```

Used Gerrit version: (2.11.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the new LDAP user to the "Administrators" group.

See more details at the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#administrators).

Comment: can you let me know which file to modify and what flag to put?

Comment: Find the "Administrators" group and add the new LDAP user to it. Your Gerrit version is really old so I don't remember exactly how the menu is named, but the Administrators group is among the other groups.

Comment: In All-Projects.git cofig file?